# C# error in printdocument and dialog works in VS but not after publishing my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printdocument, printdialog

```
private void bPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curitems = 1;
        page = 1;
        count = 1;
        printDocument1.DocumentName = tBPor.Text;
        logo = new Bitmap("Pgd_glava.jpg",true);
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
        b.Image = new Bitmap("print.png");
        b.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
        b.Click += printPreview_PrintClick;
        ((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.RemoveAt(0);
        ((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.Insert(0, b);
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

This is my code. I made my code so after i get what i want to print, it opens a print preview dialong and in it swapped the print button for a prind dialong button, which in the end prints it. I found how to do that in a question in stackoverflow.

Anyway this works perfectly fine in Visual Studio with debugging. But when i publish the project it gives me
[this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y17Fg.png)

If anyone knows what to do about this i would greatly appreciate it since I can't find exactly why this is like that, in the meanwhile i'm looking for a workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Regards Thomas!

Comment: You'll get half a million hits when you google "windows forms parameter not valid".  Very doubtful that you will need one more.

Comment: Frankly it just needed some thinking not even googling since it was obvious there was something missing just not exactly what. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone runs into the same problem and finds this the fix was actually pretty easy, but took me a bit of time to pinpoint. My problem was the fact that i was generating bitmap images from files i had in my project folder, but did not add them to rescources. So when i published my program those did not transfer with it. The simple fix is to just add them ass rescources and generate them from there
Replace :

```
logo = new Bitmap("Pgd_glava.jpg",true);
```

With:

```
logo = Properties.Resources.Pgd_glava;
```

Really is a rookie mistake on my behalf, but i just never published the programs i made up till this point.

Comment: You traded one bug for another.  This code creates *two* Bitmap objects.  One of them will never be disposed, the one created by the Pgd_glava property.  Making a deep copy of it with the Bitmap constructor is not useful, just use logo = Properties.Resource.Pgd_glava;

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)